# Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:javaPreCompileProductionDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I updated android-studio to 3.3 and gradle to 4.10.1. But before run my old application I got this error:

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:javaPreCompileProductionDebug' property 'annotationProcessorConfiguration' during up-to-date check
```

It says the problem is from my fingerprint functionality. I have this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

in my manifest that has deprecated and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Is it a bug? or it's my mistake or something?

Comment: Any news on this? I doubt it has something to do with your fingerprint permission - I'm getting the same error but I am not using the fingerprint permission. Last thing I did was update Android Studio and Gradle.

Comment: `fingerprint of input files` it has nothing to do with fingerptint on Android. It's a part of caching mechanism in Gradle.

Comment: Thanks @EugenPechanec, but do you know any solution for fixing this? and why this happend?

Comment: Each gradle task declares where its inputs and outputs are. And if some other process writes in a directory with inputs of one task, Gradle aborts with this error. If this happened only once then you need to kill all previous gradle instances after update (`gradlew --stop`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but after cleaning project and rebuild it, the problem solved :|